# Is "Http pipelining" modified in iOS6?

Tags: http, safari, ios6, pipelining

"Http pipelining" in iOS5 can cause some issues, like switching images when rendering a web page in Safari. Some sites have reported this problem, [like this one](http://tech.vg.no/2011/12/14/safari-on-ios-5-randomly-switches-images/) i.e. The origin of the problem is that pipelining "enables the browser to send several HTTP requests on the same connection before receiving the responses".

My question is: is this solved or changed in iOS6? I can't find such info.

Comment: It can only be solved in the broken servers, not in the client. Unless you want them to disable pipelining (be careful what you wish for :-)

Comment: i don't know whether it is fixed in iOS6 but we have seen this same issue in iOS7